# Creating a list field from metadata in Hakyll

Tags: metadata, listfield, hakyll

I'm trying to generate HTML for posts in Hakyll that have a `versions` entry in their metadata. For example, a post may have `versions: Python 3.4, pytest 1.5.2` which would be formatted nicely at the bottom of the post.

To achieve this, I want to create a context which loads the metadata and creates a `ListField`. Something like the following stub:

```hs
versionsCtx :: Context String
versionsCtx = listFieldWith "versions" ctx (\item -> do
    versions <- getMetadataField (itemIdentifier item) "versions"

    return $ case versions of
      Just lst -> map (mkVersinoItem . trim) $ splitAll "," lst
      Nothing  -> [])
          where ctx = field "version" (return . itemBody)
                mkVersionItem version = Item {
                    itemIdentifier = fromString ("version/" ++ version),
                    itemBody = version
                }
```

In my `post.html` template, I have:

```
...
    <section>
        $body$

        $if(versions)$
        <hr />
        <ul>
            $for(versions)$
                <li>$version$</li>
            $endfor$
        </ul>
        $else$
            <p>Fail...</p>
        $endif$
    </section>
...
```

Yet I have tried many different definitions of `versionsCtx` and found similar attempts online. None seem to work and the post is always rendered with "Fail...". What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Updated question with suggestions and clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. [`getMetadataField`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Metadata.html#v:getMetadataField) provides a `Maybe` type, which in Haskell has data constructors `Just` and `Nothing`, not `Some` and `None`.
2. The [`makeItem`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html#v:makeItem) function creates an `Item` already wrapped in a `Compiler`, resulting in the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Compiler (Item String)’ with ‘Item String’
  Expected type: Compiler [Item String]
    Actual type: Compiler [Compiler (Item String)]
```

While you could try to extract the item from it, it is probably cleaner to create an item from scratch using something like this:

```hs
mkVersionItem version = Item {
    itemIdentifier = fromString ("version/" ++ version),
    itemBody = version
}
```

3. I do not see you adding the newly created context to the post context. Did you do that?
4. As mentioned in the [docs](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#t:Context), the order `Context`s are being appended is important. It is not evident from your question, but you are probably using [`defaultContext`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#v:defaultContext), which includes [`metadataField`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#v:metadataField). You have `versions` field in the metadata block of your posts so when the `defaultContext` wins, it will make `versions` available as a string field in the template. `$if(versions)$` for some reason jumps to the `else` branch when `versions` is a string field, which explains why “Fail” is shown. You can see a more informative error in the console when you move the `for` loop outside the conditional block:

```
[ERROR] Hakyll.Web.Template.applyTemplateWith: expected ListField but got StringField for expr versions
```

---

In full the code could look something like this:

```hs
import           Data.String (fromString)

postCtx :: Context String
postCtx =
    versionsCtx `mappend`
    dateField "date" "%B %e, %Y" `mappend`
    defaultContext

versionsCtx :: Context String
versionsCtx = listFieldWith "versions" ctx (\item -> do
    versions <- getMetadataField (itemIdentifier item) "versions"

    return $ case versions of
      Just lst -> map (mkVersionItem . trim) $ splitAll "," lst
      Nothing     -> []
    )
  where
    ctx = field "version" (return . itemBody)
    mkVersionItem version = Item {
        itemIdentifier = fromString ("version/" ++ version),
        itemBody = version
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've updated my question to better reflect that my `versionsCtx` was a stub. I am adding the `versionsCtx` to the context in the rule for `match "posts/*"`. I got it to work by adding the `versionsCtx` _before_ the `postCtx` instead of _after_ it. The docs say that the order of composition of the `Context` monoid is important as fields can be overwritten but in this case, my `postCtx` does not overwrite anything (contains date, tags etc.), so I am not sure why the order matters here.

Comment: Aha! That explains it. The source for `metadataField` shows how `maybe` is used to create a string field by default. Thanks a lot! I've added a comment in my `site.hs` to make sure I remember in the future.